# How do I prevent the Page from scrolling to top when queries are added to the URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm using queries to either open or close a collapse. The queries are important since they include data that I need later on. So basically the code determines whether the queries exist or not and then mount the collapse component.

I've tried adding an onClick event that prevents default but this causes the whole link not to be fired. Also, I've seen some solutions like `?queries/` instead of `?queries` but the same result.

I'm using 'Link' from 'react-router-dom'

```js
<Link 
 className="uk-width-1-1 uk-button uk-button-grey" 
 to={inRouteContext(`${createQuery(location, [{inactivate: 
 item.inventoryCounter.toString()}])}`)}
>
 <FormattedMessage {...MESSAGES.inactivateUnit}/>
</Link>
```

How do I stop the page from scrolling to top when I click the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Scroll Restoration](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration).(official docs)

Comment: Thanks! I found a scrollTopContainer in the code that did exactly this! Changed location !== prev.Location to loaction.pathname !== prev.location.pathname

Comment: Thanks wonderful that it helped you. If this is an answer then please mark it as one. @MarlonBerdefy